# Display a local icon in IE extension

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, plugins, https, bho

I have read the following [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/84f96fa0-8b72-4293-97b4-1b497adbee6a/).
I'm trying to embed an icon using a BHO extension. However, the res:// protocol doesn't work in HTTPS sites.
Is there a workaround or alternative to display local images in HTTPS sites?

Comment: Somewhere on the page. For example, the extension adds a flag on all links of all pages that lead to Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question...

It is possible to embed the image as BASE64 string.
For example,

```
myImg.setAttribute('src', "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG........");
```

This way, you don't need to use the res:// protocol.
You can encode the image in BASE64 at runtime (while the extension is loading for example) or encoding it in advance (like in this example).
And most importantly, this works over HTTPS too.